# disable panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to disable panels in asp.net like when manager is login then they cannot able to see supervisor
and also manager and supervisor designations are also defined in table like when

```
1 supervisor
2  manager
```

and i try this but i try this but i not work

```
if (Session["UserDesignation"].ToString() == "2")
{
    Manager.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    Manager.Visible = false;
}
if (Session["UserDesignation"].ToString() == "1")
{
    SuperVisiorPanel.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    SuperVisiorPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

and in login form

```
int desginid = Convert.ToInt16(aa.spdesign(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value));
Session["UserDesignationID"] = desginid;

if (users == 1)
{
    Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
    Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;
    Session["UserDesignationID"] =  desginid;
    Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

    Response.Redirect("AdminOp.aspx");
}
else if (users == 2)
{
    Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
    Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;
    Session["UserDesignationID"] = desginid;

    Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

    Response.Redirect("upload.aspx");
}
```

here above 1 and code is user type ID

any help?

Comment: pnlchk.Enabled=true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable/disable asp.net panel

```
SuperVisiorPanel.Enabled = false;
SuperVisiorPanel.Enabled = True;
```

To hide/show asp.net panel

```
SuperVisiorPanel.Visible = false;
SuperVisiorPanel.Visible = True;
```

Comment: u mean that i want to remove this ....if (Session["UserDesignation"].ToString() == "2")
{